# JUnit assertThat: check that Object equals String

Tags: java, android, junit, assertions

I have `Map` declared as following:

```
Map<String, Object> data
```

I put a `String` in it and verify its value like this:

```
assertEquals("value", data.get("key"));
```

Now, I'd like to rewrite the verification to use `assertThat` instead of `assertEquals`. I've tried the following:

```
assertThat(data.get("key"), equalTo("value"));
```

And of course it didn't work because of type mismatch:

> `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.String>', required: 'org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super java.lang.Object>' less...`

Explicit type cast of the first argument to `String` helps, but I'd like to avoid it. For example `assertEquals` doesn't require type cast.
So, how can I check that the value, which was put into `Map` object, declared above, is equal to particular `String`, using the `assertThat` method?

Comment: casting the data.get to a String might help

Comment: Yes, it helps. The point is that I want to avoid explicit type cast. Looking for a way to make it work like assertEquals but with assertThat.

Comment: `Matcher.<Object>equalTo("value")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "more assertThat" way of doing things would be:

```
Map<String, Object> expectedData = Collections.singletonMap("key", "value");

asssertThat(data, is(expectedData));
```

Please note:

- Maybe you need type hints for the call to singletonMap
- Besides the *is* matcher, there are other matchers that would allow you to check that data *contains* your "expected" map data

For your specific problem: that is caused because how generics come into play here; it might be sufficient to use `(String) data.get("key")` - to tell the compiler that the "actual" argument is of type String.

In the end - I have no idea what your problem is. I wrote down this piece of code:

```
public void test() {
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("key", "value");
    assertThat(data.get("key"), is("value"));

    Map<String, Object> expectedData = Collections.singletonMap("key", "value");
    assertThat(data, is(expectedData));
}
```

It compiles fine, and the unit test runs and passes. In other words: actually I am unable to repro your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately "is" has the same issue as "equalsTo". It looks like I can't achieve what I want without explicit type cast to String.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Things work for me (both ways) without any casting (but to be precise: using Java8). In Java7, type inference might give you a problem; requiring you to put down that cast.

Comment: Hmm, checked again exactly your example  and experienced the same issue as before. So it definitely looks like version mismatch of anything. I'll continue researching and checking.

Comment: Lets be precise about wording: there is no "version" mismatch. What I am saying is: my code works fine with Java8. When you are using an older version from Java, the *type inference* works less good; therefore older Java might only work with hardcoded casts.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant. Sorry, if it confused you. At least your comment shows that the desired approach is working.

Answer (score 3):

try this

`assertThat(data.get("key"), equalTo("value"))`

or

```
    assertThat(data.get("key"), CoreMatchers.equalTo("value"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" before answering a question.